# How can we calculate pion decay constant in Chiral Perturbation Theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, weak-interaction, pions

[image]

The above diagram is a one-loop contribution to the pion decay constant $f_\pi$. For example in [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(87)91156-7) paper (Eq.7) they have written down the pion decay constant to one loop, but the calculation is not given. Usually the pion decay constant is defined in the following way:  $$ \langle 0|J^a_\mu|\pi^b(p)\rangle = i p_\mu f_\pi \delta^{ab}$$ ([link](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0210398), Eq.4.19). I wanted to know how exactly are these two pictures related. That is, how do we extract the one-loop correction to $f_\pi$ by calculating the amplitude corresponding to the above diagram, in the context of Chiral Perturbation Theory or simply using the Lagrangian of the above mentioned [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(87)91156-7) Eq.3.

I have searched the internet extensively but could not find a place where such a calculation is done explicitly, so any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: At the risk of this being tagged as not on topic, I have to ask, have you reached a conclusion on this subject? Check page 36, (5.2) of http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9509427, and let me know if it helps, cause I'm curious as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, you cannot calculate the pion decay constant in chiral perturbation theory. All you can do is adjust the parameters in your n-loop calculation so that the physical value is reproduced. The standard reference for the one-loop renormalization of ChPTh is Gasser and Leutwyler, Chiral Perturbation Theory to One Loop, Annals of Physics 158, 142 (1984).

Comment: Thanks. By the way that is what I meant, reproducing the standard result. And in the Leutwyler paper also the calculation is not given in connection to a Feynman loop picture.